# How to move VM from one vCenter to another using Ansible?

Tags: virtual-machine, centos, vmware, deployment, ansible

I am using Ansible with PyVmomi to create and deploy VMs. Is there a way to move VM from one vCenter to another? The vCenters are in same network setting. Or, is that possible to clone a VM/template from one vCenter to the VM in another vCenter? Which module can I use in pyVmomi?

Comment: " is that possible to clone a VM/template from one vCenter to the VM in another vCenter?" - This would clone the machine.  You don't want to do this.  It would create havoc on your network if specific hostnames are being used, for things to work.

Comment: I mean clone and rename the machine, and also re-IP. Besides, it's a CentOS machine, not a Windows one.